# WebStorm stuck on /usr/local/bin/node after update

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I did an update of WebStorm this morning. Since the update, my project will no longer run properly. It gets stuck on `/usr/local/bin/node`, nothing else gets executed. Does anyone else have this issue?

More specifically, I am talking about the green 'run node app.js' arrow button on the top right. I have set the run configuration to always do `node app.js` but that button is not working anymore. If I go into terminal and manually type in `node app.js`, the project will run.

Screenshot of run configuration:

[image]

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your run configuration

Comment: @lena added, please see question

Comment: Since it's complaining about the working directory, I'd look at fixing that.  But you also need to specify the file you want to run in the `JavaScript file:` input

Comment: specify `app.js` as `JavaScript file:` and make sure to set the folder it's located in as a `working directory`

Comment: @DaveV you are right, I simply put app.js in that field and now everything works again. For some reason, it got lost when I did the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's complaining about the working directory, I'd look at fixing that. But you also need to specify the file you want to run in the `JavaScript file:` input